# JavaScript clicking all inputs with value "abc"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a javascript code line which will click on all input tags who's value is "abc" on a web page.

```
<input value="abc" onclick="require(&quot;InlineFriendInviter&quot;).sendInvite(&quot;216532985099211&quot;, &quot;100002543193060&quot;, &quot;u_1h_2l&quot;, &quot;send&quot;, &quot;admin_tip&quot;);" type="submit" id="u_1h_2m">
```

When i tried,

```
$('input[value="abc"]').click();
```

I am getting error

```
Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","input[value=\"abc\"]"]]]>
```

Comment: Please send money.

Comment: Does the page include multiple libraries? What does `jQuery === $` give you? `$('input[value="abc"]')` doesn't use an id selector, so the error doesn't fit for jQuery.

Comment: I am trying this code in chrome java console

Comment: The console is probably messed up

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[value="abc"]').click();
```

Comment: i updated my question as getting error sir :(

Comment: Why are you using special characters inside your onclick inline script? Problem comes from here

Comment: its a very complicated web page developed by senior developers

Comment: Do you think that single quotes would make a difference?

Comment: @roasted It's just HTML encoded and is similar to escaping, `\"`. http://jsfiddle.net/zsHyS/